# VBA subroutine that changes all worksheet names in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a subroutine that will allow me to read the names of all the worksheets in a workbook, and convert the names to all upper-case letters.

Comment: Select post as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        sh.Name = UCase(sh.Name)
    Next sh
End Sub
```